# How does $ \sqrt[3]{x}^2-\sqrt{y}^2$ become $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}^6-\sqrt{y}^6}{\sqrt[3]{x}^4+\sqrt[3]{x}^2\cdot\sqrt{y}^2+\sqrt{y}^4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with some algebra, how can we end up with the right hand side in the following?
$$
\sqrt[3]{x}^2-\sqrt{y}^2 = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}^6-\sqrt{y}^6}{\sqrt[3]{x}^4+\sqrt[3]{x}^2\cdot\sqrt{y}^2+\sqrt{y}^4} \tag 1
$$

Attempts:

The exponents in the numerator is 6 and on the left hand side it is 2 so I multiply with exponent of 4:
$$
\sqrt[3]{x}^2-\sqrt{y}^2
\cdot
\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}^4+\sqrt{y}^4}{\sqrt[3]{x}^4+\sqrt{y}^4}
=\frac{
 \sqrt[3]{x}^6
 +\sqrt[3]{x}^2\sqrt{y}^4
 -\sqrt{y}^2\sqrt[3]{x}^4
 -\sqrt{y}^6
}{
\sqrt[3]{x}^4+\sqrt{y}^4
} \tag 2
$$
And I'm stuck here.

If I instead multiply with a exponent of 2 I get
$$
\sqrt[3]{x}^2-\sqrt{y}^2
\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}^2+\sqrt{y}^2}{\sqrt[3]{x}^2+\sqrt{y}^2}
=\frac{
\sqrt[3]{x}^4-\sqrt{y}^4
}{
\sqrt[3]{x}^2+\sqrt{y}^2
} \tag 3
$$
But I'm also stuck here.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = (\sqrt[3]{x})^2 = x^{2/3}, b = (\sqrt{y})^2 = y$.

Then just use the identity $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab - b^2)$.